# schema modifications according to new requirements

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a Database used to manage products/items of a shop system. The table structure looks like

```
Categories
----------------------------
id
name
description
active
created
modified



Products
----------------------------
id
name
description
active
created
modified
id_category
```

now i am interested in using this database for multiple shops. what will be the best possible way to modify the schema. By adding a `id_shop` in each table? or is there a better way

Thank you

Comment: Should the categories and/or products be shareable between multiple shops? In other words, are we talking about 1:N or M:N relationship?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple schemas versus enormous tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340721/multiple-schemas-versus-enormous-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Shops
----------
shop_id
ShopName
AhopAddr
...

Categories
----------------------------
id
name
description
active
created
modified
shop_id

Products
----------------------------
id
name
description
active
created
modified
id_category
shop_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a basic compromise is the following schema

[image]

In this case you can ad more categories to a single product