# Multiple Client Databases using Single Schema - is that possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, multi-tenant

I am new to SQL Server 2008, but having read about Schemas I have this question.

Currently, for every new client we have, I have to manually create a new database and then import all objects (tables/views/stored procs etc) from an existing database. Now whenever there is any update from the Developers (eg. Change in Table Structure, Stored Procs etc), the changes have to be made in all the databases. I am tired of using DBComparer to fix the differences in databases.

**Is it possible to have one "Master Schema" which contains all the tables/stored procedures/views?** So that all "Client Databases" could refer to this "Master Schema", but still be able to maintain its own Data without any problem.

Comment: No, schemas can be used to logically group objects within a database. There is (as far as I know) no concept of a *shared* schema between databases.

Comment: Instead you should make sure that the structure for all your production databases are exactly the same, generate a script that does the necessary updates and run that script in all databases. There should be no need to run DBCompararer against all db's.

Comment: @Mikael - then whats the best solution for maintaining multiple dbs in the above scenario?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - i wondered if the DBs could "share" the schema so that all updates reach to the clients without having to run the scripts as u mentioned. This could reduce chances of errors/omissions by a great deal

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Schemata live in the database.

Multiple Client databases SIMILAR Schema, yes, but you have to upgrade one by one. The Schema is not in master - it is in every database and this can not be changed. In fact, every Schema is totally independant and you can have 01 "identical Content" Schemata in one database.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have a single "master" schema. It's probably *not* possible to have this "master" schema, and still have each client maintain their own data *without any problem*.

What you're looking at is a kind of multi-tenant architecture. Microsoft's [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) is a good introduction to the issues.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8343142/562459) had an overview of the various trade-offs you need to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess I have to settle with the "scripting" options only because sharing Databases will be a bit too hard for the clients. And for backups/restores as well