# HIPAA Compliant Architecture

Tags: database-design, multi-tenant, database-administration, hipaa

I am developing a Medical Billing Software and should be HIPAA complaint. My current architecture is using separate database for each tenant. But I need to change it to a Multi tenant architecture. So Is there any problem for HIPAA with Multi tenant architecture ?

Is it possible to get any Document/Proof related to this topic ?

Answer (score 1):

"One database per tenant" *is* a multi-tenant architecture; others on the architectural spectrum include "one schema per tenant" and "every tenant shares every table". See, for example, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340721/multiple-schemas-versus-enormous-tables), and especially the linked article at the end.

As far as I can tell, [HIPAA doesn't prohibit "every tenant shares every table"](http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/enforcement/audit/protocol.html).  Your source for proof should be somewhere on the [US Dept of Heath and Human Services](http://www.hhs.gov/) web site.

Comment: Source of proof is a hard one with HIPAA. You may find it on the HHS site if you're going to find it anywhere. I think most vendors consider their audit reports to be the source of proof.